# Angular 4 Cyclic Dependency with Startup Service using Router

Tags: angular, router, cyclic-dependency

Have been getting a cyclic dependency error when using a startup service that depends on "Router" within my Angular 4 application.

**Error I get is as follows:**

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"):
>   in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

I have created a very simple plunker which demonstrates the issue. Which can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/fv6DmZ14JmdUDsgO4H53

**Background:**
I am trying to run some startup code which will require use of the router within my angular 4 application.  However, as soon as I add a router dependency in the constructor of my startup service, I get the cyclic dependency error stated above.

The line in question is the inclusion of the constructor dependency on the router, in the src/AppStartupService.ts file on line 7 in the constructor:

```
private router: Router
```

If I remove this constructor dependency everything works.

I am not seeing where the cyclic dependency relies.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. It doesn't contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and a plunk doesn't explain what exactly you need the router for in this service.

Comment: @estus- I need the router to perform some google analytic operations that are specific to our environment here.  So, including that detail I think detracts from the problem I am trying to figure out. I was able to whittle the problem down to the inclusion of the "router" as a constructor dependency in the file specified at the line specified. My question is why does this cyclic dependency error exist

Comment: Cyclic dependency exists because a router is instantiated after app initialization (APP_INITIALIZER), so you can't inject it during init. Whether there is a workaround or not depends on how you use the router. It's unclear how 'google analytic operations' are related to the router. MCVE is not a distraction but a requirement, otherwise the question is considered off-topic and can be closed.